# My Account is hacked. I send money in and its instantly sent to another address. I need to know how to stop this code from running? any thoughts?

Tags: hack

I need to know how to stop a hack algorithm code from running on my meta-mask. As soon as I put any money into this account it is immediately sent to another address.  I believe to someone called fake_phishing.  I have a problem.  I have a transaction that will be coming in and I need this algorithm that sends it out to stop somehow so I can beat the person stealing my crytpo to the punch when it finally arrives to this account.

Comment: Hey @Twok. Try revoking all token approvals on that wallet: https://revoke.cash

Comment: That should help in case you approved a malicious address to spend your tokens. If your seed phrase has been compromised, then it would be very difficult to regain control over it.

Comment: Its a sweeper bot.  How do I stop the sweeper bot?

Comment: You might find this guide by Metamask useful in fighting the sweeper boy: https://support.metamask.io/hc/en-us/articles/5716855323675-Fighting-back-against-sweeper-bots

Answer (score 1):

Stop using it.

It is already compromised, and your secret key is already stolen. Don't send any transactions to this address! There is no way to fix it.